# Locating multiple ffmpeg installations

Tags: software-installation, ffmpeg, mpv-media-player

I use multiple tools that rely on ffmpeg, a couple of which have downloaded different versions of ffmpeg from the one provided in the package repositories (e.g., mpv and moviepy via imageio). The separate ffmpeg binaries for these programs have not interfered with each other, but I am having difficulties related to some inconsistencies between the different versions.

My question is: how do I locate the different versions of ffmpeg (other than the ubuntu package) that exist on my system so that I can point everything toward the binary of the most current version (in my case, the ffmpeg running with mpv)?

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with `find / -name ffmpeg`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experimenting a bit more, I was able to locate the alternate ffmpeg binaries installed by other programs using `locate` and `egrep`:

```
locate mpv | egrep 'ffmpeg$'
locate imageio | egrep 'ffmpeg$'
```

And then use `alias` to redirect the `ffmpeg` command to the most up-to-date binary without breaking other dependencies.

Comment: @mchid yeah, I did build mpv from [source](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv-build), but it left binaries in `~/mpv-build/build_libs/bin/` and `~/mpv-build/ffmpeg_build/`, and not in `/usr/local/bin/` for whatever reason

Comment: @hb Okay, `/usr/local/bin` is not used because this is a local install.

Answer (score 1):

There are two commands you can use to determine which binary is in use and also if there is more than one `ffmpeg` installed.

First, to determine which binary is currently in use, run the following command:

```
which ffmpeg
```

Next, you can show where `ffmpeg` files and binaries are by running the following command:

```
whereis ffmpeg
```

The `whereis` command should show where the different binaries are if there is more than one and the binaries are usually under a `bin` directory.

Comment: hm, it seems `whereis` only gives me the current binary in use, but doesn't give me the locations of the ffmpeg binaries installed by mpv and imageio, whereas `locate` does (though along with a lot of other locations I don't need)

Comment: @hb_ It looks like `whereis` does not work when trying to find something installed locally.

Comment: @hb_ This is maybe because the directory is not in your `$PATH`. I have stuff installed in `/home/$USER/.local/bin` that shows up but  `/home/$USER/.local/bin` is in my `$PATH`.

Comment: thanks for clarifying this! `/home/$USER/.local/bin` was indeed not in my path

Comment: @hb_ I wouldn't mess with it if you found a way to make it work so I wouldn't add that to my path unless needed. Besides, it didn't look like  `ffmpeg` was installed in `/home/$USER/.local/bin`. I was just using `/home/$USER/.local/bin` as an example because that is where some python stuff shows up if installed locally and `whereis` does show the python apps installed because this is in my `$PATH`.